# jQuery lightbox-effect on click div resize

Tags: jquery, html, resize

I have code similar to: http://jsfiddle.net/jYasG/4/

### HTML

```
<a id="open" href="#">test1</a>
<div id="boxbg"><a id="close" href="#">tatastat</a></div>    
<div id="bgfade"></div>    
<br>
<br>
<br>

<a id="open" href="#">test2</a>
<div id="boxbg"><a id="close" href="#">test2<br><br>test2<br><br></a></div>    
<div id="bgfade"></div>
```

### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a#open").click(function() {
        var width1 = $(this).next('div').width();
        var width2 = width1 / 2 * -1;
        $("#boxbg").css({
            "margin-left": width2
        });

        var height1 = $(this).next('div').height();
        var height2 = height1 / 2 * -1;
        $("#boxbg").css({
            "margin-top": height2
        });


        $(this).next('div').fadeIn(300);
        $("#bgfade").fadeIn(300);
        return false;
    })

    $("a#close").click(function() {
        $(this).next().fadeIn(300);
        $("#bgfade, #boxbg").fadeOut(300);
        return false;
    })
})
```

When the user clicks on test1, the div box is perfectly centered vertically and horizontally; I'm trying to make it so that test2 does the same effect when it is clicked.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: quick look advice ID should be unique

Comment: You really won't get proper results unless all of your id's are unique.  Use class names if you want the same functionality across multiple objects.

Comment: wow quick responses, the class thing solved it, perfect, thanks guys! appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/calebgray/a6Ame/

Comment: Just so you know, the jQuery Dialog class does this for you, with advanced features like autosize, loading ajax, etc.

Comment: See it [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal), the code is simple: `$('#popup').dialog({modal:true});`